# css style tag for div

Tags: css

I have a page with this structure:

```
<div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" >
            <div class="question buttons clearfix nobg">
                <input id="k3" name="k" type="hidden" value="">
                <input id="h3" name="h" type="hidden" value="b07e0bc1c3751d34acbef5b8546b29ae">
                <input id="s3" name="s" type="hidden" value="eyJwYWdlcGF0aCI6IFswXX0=">
                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="SID" value="1f7d2a9b3b9450ce2dd746bf0005ebe1">
                <input type="hidden" name="_terminated_redirect" value="">
                <div id="button-fix" class="button-fix" style="text-align:center">
                    <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="">
                    <input id="next-submit-button" type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to align   to center using css. What will be style tag for it ?

Please suggest

Comment: What do you want to align at center? all div?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow What you want to align to center?

Comment: I want to center align  <div id="button-fix" class="button-fix" style="text-align:center" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="">
                    <input id="next-submit-button" type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit">
                </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a width on your outer DIV (maybe give it an ID of wrapper or similar)  and then set it's margins - see below:

```
#wrapper {
    width:960px; /* whatever you want this to be */
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Strange, here's a fiddle showing what I'd suggested working. I can only assume that there is some other css or something on your page affecting it. http://jsfiddle.net/MnPRf/

Comment: Sorry, I sent a part of html. Please see jsfiddle.net/E2zVb/1. I need to center align button and radio buttons and add a little bit padding

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #button-fix {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

Here's a demonstration of your examle in **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2zVb/)**

Comment: It didnt work for me. Using these styles will center align button ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow didn't realize you wanted to only center the button. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I sent a part of html. Please see  http://jsfiddle.net/E2zVb/1/. I need to center align button and radio buttons and add a little bit padding.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow My answer shows how an element can be centered inside a `div`. Please use it as a starting point, I can't write your code for you.

Comment: I can not modify the html and can not add wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS:

```
​#container {margin: 10% auto;}​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/As2yB/